# Javascript and html code with Text Box

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, vb.net

I have to insert text box at button.click event.
for this I've been using this code implement it, in ASPX.VB file.

below code refecting attached screen shot, which displaying the textbox beside to the delete button.

Issue:

Example: If we insert any simple text box in ASPX page, then we can take that textbox id and we can play with that in aspx.vb file . in the same way I would like to play with the below code by having the textbox Id. How?

How I need to take this text boxId(id = ""txtExperimentalStressdays"") and save the user entered data into database.

Just I would to do as below:
Calling the mothod to insert the text box data
calltextboxdatainsertmethod(txtExperimentalStressdays.text)

Issue is, to do as in the above line, this text box code won't work, because it is in the "" quotes.

[image]

```
testTypeNode.Text = testTypeNode.Text & "" & _  
" <img src=""../images/delete_16x.ico""" & _  
" style=""text-align:bottom; cursor:pointer;"" alt=""Delete TestType""" & _  
" title=""Delete TestType"" onclick=""javascript:if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete? Any running tests will be aborted!'))" & _  
" {" & ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(btnDeleteTestType, "" & sequenceNode.Value.ToString & _  
WordSeparationChar & testTypeNode.Value.ToString & "") & ";};"" />" & _  
"<inputtype= ""text""id= ""txtExperimentalStressdays""name=""ExperimentalStressdays""size=""4"" title=""Pleaseenter the Experimental Stressdays"" javascript:onfocusdown(/>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using "\" as escape character in you code.

Thanks

Comment: Is this shold like id = ""\txtExperimentalStressdays""   in the above code

Comment: You should follow "<img src=\"../images/delete_16x.ico\" style=\"text-align:bottom; cursor:pointer;\" alt=\"Delete TestType\"  this style

Answer (score 0):

something that might be considerably easier is to go ahead and create the textbox, but use the javascript to change the visibility. 
As an example, your textbox could start hidden:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtBox" runat="server" CssClass="1887txt" Text="" Style="display: none;"></asp:TextBox>
```

And then, OnClick of a button (just attach the javascript function either directly from the .ascx or in the code behind using the *.Attributes.Add("onClick", "yourfunction") method.
Say you did it the first way so your button in the .ascx looks like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" CssClass="1887lbl" OnClientClick=:firejs(); return false;"
                 Text="Submit" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
```

And then your javascript function

```
function firejs(){
   var txt = !GetServerControl("input", "txtBox");
   txt.style.display = "none";
}
```

Just an idea. Not sure what you're trying to do exactly...

-sf